# Implementación de jwt token en spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security

He implementado una solución para autenticarme con JWT Token en spring boot que funciona perfectamente salvo dos cosas, no redirecciona a la página desde la que se hizo la petición antes de redireccionar a la página de login y no funciona el SuccessHandler. Por las pruebas que he hecho a mi me parece que el problema es debido a que no se hace una atenticación con exito(success authentication) pero no se como resolverlo.
El código es el siguiente:

securityconfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccess;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = mongoUserDetails();
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/search_posts", "/wall/**", "/resources/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**", "/api/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/exams/**").hasAuthority(Role.STUDENT.toString())
                .anyRequest().authenticated()                
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccess)
                .and().csrf().disable();



     // Apply JWT
        http.apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
        //filtro para poner JWT en la cabecera del request
        http.addFilterBefore(new RequestWrapperFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);       
        //http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.httpBasic().disable();




                //.apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }//.and()//.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint())

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Unauthorized");
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService mongoUserDetails() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

}
```

el jwttoken filter, filtro que comprueba el token

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) req);
        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication auth = token != null ? jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token) : null;
            SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            sc.setAuthentication(auth);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

El provider del jwttoken

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret}")
    private String secretKey = Constants.SECRET;

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.expire-length:3600000}")
    private long validityInMilliseconds = 10800000; // 3h

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    }

    public String createToken(String username, Set<Role> roles) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        claims.put("roles", roles);
        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliseconds);
        return Jwts.builder()//
            .setClaims(claims)//
            .setIssuedAt(now)//
            .setExpiration(validity)//
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretKey)//
            .compact();
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getUsername(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    public String getUsername(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
         String bearerToken = req.getHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith(Constants.BEARER)) {
            return bearerToken.substring(Constants.BEARER.length(), bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token);
            if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JwtException("Expired or invalid JWT token");
        }
    }
}
```

y donde se configura el filtro

```
public class JwtConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtConfigurer(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtTokenFilter customFilter = new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

y para finalizar la apirest donde se crea el token y se autentifica

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository users;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler ash;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public void login(@ModelAttribute("user") Users user, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {      

        try {
            //set authentication
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));
            SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            sc.setAuthentication(auth);

            //create a token
            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(user.getUsername(), this.users.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).getRoles());
            //create and set a cookie
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(Constants.TOKEN, token);
            cookie.setMaxAge(3 * 60 * 60); // expires in 3 hours
            cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            //add cookie to response
            response.addCookie(cookie);

            //call to onauthenticationsuccess
            //ash.onAuthenticationSuccess(req, response, auth);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid email/password supplied");
        }
    }
```

Por favor estoy un poco perdido y no encuentro la solución al problema, es cierto que spring te redirecciona a la pagina solicitada antes de la pagina de login? Hay forma de redireccionar a la página anterior antes del login?
gracias